# Check if the refund for consumable IAP for apple is refunded fully or partially and its amount?

Tags: ios

we want to know whether refund requested by the user for consumable IAP of Apple is refunded fully or partially. I can get revocation date on when the refund was processed but I also want to know whether the user got refund fully or partially and its amount as well if possible.

we tried to get transaction info and also refund history of App Store Server API but we are only getting revocation date and revocation reason but we also want to know if the refund was processed as fully or partially and how much money did the user got back on refund successful. Also checked the webhook data we get for REFUND notificationType, we don't get back any field which helps us identify whether refund was full or partial and its amount as well.